# Using java.util.List in C# with IKVM

Tags: c#, ikvm

I'm trying to make a call to a java application using a C# client. The object that is sent is of type  java.util.List. I've added the required IKVM assemblies to my C# project. I'm just unsure how I should instantiate the List object.  As it's just on interface I can't just create a new instance of it.

```
 java.util.List myList = new java.util.List();
```

Could someone provide me help on using this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `java.util.List myList = new java.util.ArrayList();`

Comment: That did it. Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: @AVD can you please post your comment as an answer so tat it may be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know that the type `java.util.List` is an interface (and it is not a `class` type so we can't instantiate). You need to use the any class type which is an implementation of `java.util.List`.

```
java.util.List myList = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

Or even better to use type parameter:

```
java.util.List<Integer> myList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: IKVM (as of this writing) doesn't support Java generics due to type erasure. Using the generic class ArrayList does work though.

Answer (score 3):

In java there are `Iterators`

sample usage:

```
        java.util.List matches = new java.util.ArrayList();
        //stuff to add elements to list
        Iterator it = matches.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            RuleMatch m = (RuleMatch)it.next();
            Console.WriteLine("Potential error:" + m.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate `java.util.List`, as it's an interface.